# Calculate Median Value Using InfoPath Forms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I tired searching everywhere before I decided to post here.

I have a complex requirement which I made simple, I have 10 text box fields in my InfoPath form and in 11th texbox, I need to populate the Median of all the 10 text box's values.

Is there anyway I can achieve it using InfoPath forms?

Someone has posted below sample form which calculates the Median value but it's calculating it in Calculated Values which is not getting deployed on my library where I intend to use it further (like fetching data from library)

http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/storage/41/85741/Averages.xsn

Any help guys?

Comment: Could you use the formula for calc the median on field change on the textboxes, or on submit, to set the 11th textbox instead.

Comment: I couldnt found any formula in InfoPath that gives Median value!!

Comment: Any help guys? Not sure of this!!

Comment: Ah ok, I thought there was a formula in the Averages.xsn you found that you could use on submit or something. Tbh I have never calculated the median with InfoPath. An alternative is to promote the 10 fields to SharePoint and use a Calculated field in SharePoint with: =Median(field1,field2,etc)

Comment: I guess than there is no way to calculate median in InfoPath, I can definetly use SharePoint's field and Calculated field (I guess that's what I will be going) but as per requirement, users wanted to show the result value before submitting, using sharepoint fields, they will have to submit it to show the results, I guess that makes sense!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and getting help I found out the solution of my above problem.

I have updated the detailed answer [here](http://naimishpandya.wordpress.com/2013/01/23/calculate-median-value-using-infopath-forms/)